# Possibility of winning a best of 7 series with varying probabilities?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

> There are two teams, A and B. The first two games are played at the
> home field of A, the following three are played at the home field of
> B, and the last two are played back at home field of A. The
> probability of winning on their own home fields for each team is 3/5.
> If one team wins 4 matches the remaining matches aren't played.
>
> a) what is the probability of team A winning the series
>
> b) what is the expected number of games the series goes to

So far the only solution I could think of for a) is finding how many ways a given team can win 4-0, 4-1, 4-2, 4-3, adding them all up and dividing it by the every possibility, but I feel this is too slow [(calculating for Team A)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTZWL.png). and that theres a better way to solve it.

What are the different ways/most efficient way this could be solved?

Edit: I ended up solving it by doing what I said in the paragraph above, which gave me, [A win conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BwDU.png), [B win conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taLiU.png), and [Final Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmNt3.png).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think that would be the correct way to solve the problem, to calculate Team A winning in 4 games, 5 games, 6 games or 7 games.  If you draw a table with two columns of P[A=win] and P[B=win] for each game, then you will have a lot of 5's in the denominators of your expression and 3's and 2's in the numerators which might simplify your calculations as you build up to more games.

Comment: Why not make a Monte Carlo simulation?

Comment: Hint for a: Show that this is equivalent to pretending that all 7 games are played, and the winner is the one that wins 4 or more games. Then relate this to a certain binomial expansion.

Comment: With enough space (and some patience), a tree diagram could be a good visual aid to solving both problems.